# change every value of a 2d array in python

Tags: python, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have a matrix like:

```
matrix = [
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0]
]
```

and I have to assign a value to every element based on the formula (2 ∗ i + 3 ∗ j) mod 6, where i and j are the indexes.
I'm using the following code to iterate and assign value:

```
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
        matrix[i][j] = (((2 * i) + (3 * j)) % 6)
```

but I have this output:

```
matrix = [
    [4, 1, 4],
    [4, 1, 4],
    [4, 1, 4]
]
```

instead of the expected:

```
matrix = [
    [0, 3, 0],
    [2, 5, 2],
    [4, 1, 4]
]
```

how can I solve this issue? Also, I can't use NumPy to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is NOT how you created your array!  If you did, it would work.  What you did instead is

```
matrix = [[0]*3]*3
```

That gives you three references to a SINGLE list object, not three separate list objects.  Initialize it as

```
matrix = [[0]*3 for _ in range(3)]
```

or better yet, use numpy.

Comment: It worked like magic! Felt like you were behind me watching my code LOL. But thanks for the answer, I didn't knew about this object difference.

Comment: Well, I only recognize it because we've all done the same thing at one time or another.